# Proving the convergence of $ u_ {n} $ defined in pieces

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am demonstrating the convergence of the sequence:

$$u_{n+1}=\begin{cases} -\frac{u_{n}}{2}, \hspace{1.1cm} u_{n}<0\\
u_{n}-2u_{n}^{3}, \hspace{0.2cm} u_{n}\geqslant 0 \end{cases}$$

where $u_{0}=1$. If it clearly converges, it does so at $ 0 $ but I don't know how to show convergence. One way I came up with is to try to prove that $ | u_ {n + 1} | <c | u_ {n} | $ for $ n $ big enough and $ 0 <c <1 $. Another way is to try to prove that the sequence of negative terms is increasing and that of positive terms is decreasing. Any help is welcome

Comment: Don't worry about the piecewise definition. It's not difficult to show, with induction, that $u_n \ge 0$ for $n \ge 2$. You can also show that, from this point on, the sequence is monotone decreasing, which proves it converges.

Comment: Thank you very much